# Bash, sed, get 2 specific string from lines from html, store as csv

Tags: bash, csv, sed

**Question**

I parsed html file, here is example of results.

```
...

<p style="position:absolute;top:552px;left:26px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1729"><a href="114281">114281</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:403px;left:688px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1729"><a href="114282">114282</a></p>
<!-- Page 18 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:956px;left:485px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="145041">145041</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1192px;left:485px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="112476">112476</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:675px;left:485px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="145040">145040</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:430px;left:59px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="430258">430258</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1063px;left:51px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="107267">107267</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:586px;left:246px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="145042">145042</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:156px;left:446px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1829"><a href="440332">440332</a></p>
<!-- Page 19 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:1205px;left:53px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>1&#160;790,-&#160;</b>|<a href="457710">&#160;457710</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1205px;left:634px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>2 290,-&#160;</b>|<a href="464429">&#160;464429</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:924px;left:353px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>2 590,-&#160;</b>|<a href="464430">&#160;464430</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:924px;left:53px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>1&#160;990,-&#160;</b>|<a href="457711">&#160;457711</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:1205px;left:354px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>2&#160;990,-&#160;</b>|<a href="465337">&#160;465337</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:344px;left:642px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>4&#160;990,-&#160;</b>|<a href="460435">&#160;460435</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:924px;left:634px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>3&#160;990,-&#160;</b>|<a href="464432">&#160;464432</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:617px;left:641px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft1938"><b>2&#160;990,-&#160;</b>|<a href="436458">&#160;436458</a></p>
<!-- Page 20 -->
<p style="position:absolute;top:589px;left:637px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft2029"><a href="217822">217822</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:853px;left:32px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft2029"><a href="217824">217824</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:616px;left:333px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft2029"><a href="218228">218228</a></p>
<p style="position:absolute;top:894px;left:333px;white-space:nowrap" class="ft2029"><a href="226105">226105</a></p>

...
```

Is there some simple way get output below from output above? First value is `page` from `<!-- Page PAGE -->`, second value is `NUMBER` from `<a href="NUMBER">`. And in case `PAGE` is `<!-- Page 1 -->`, replace by string `Title` instead `1`.

```
...

18,145041
18,112476
18,145040
18,107275
18,145042
18,440332
19,457710
19,464429

...
```

**I tried** just for numbers this.

```
grep '<a href=' file.html | sed -n '/<a href="/,/">/p'
```

But no effect.

Thanks.

Comment: @JNevill Thanks, but I think is it possible, what I need. I just want use `sed` to get string between `<a href="` and `">` from each line. Then compare via some script input and ouptut file to generate file like `csv` format as I want.

Comment: Totally. I mean it's already parsed HTML and you have everything in nice rows. So thinking through this in `awk` for instance, you can split your line/record on like `href="` and then grab everything numeric until a non-numeric is hit. It just feels like something that would be easier from the original HTML file that lead to this extract with a proper parser. Your already a good way down the rabbit-hole though, so that little extra bit might not be too unreasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May some like this `awk` do?

```
awk '/Page/ {h=$3} /-- Page 1 --/ {h="Title"} /href=/ && h {split($0,a,"\"");print h","a[6]}'
18,145041
18,112476
18,145040
18,430258
18,107267
18,145042
18,440332
19,457710
19,464429
19,464430
19,457711
19,465337
19,460435
19,464432
19,436458
20,217822
20,217824
20,218228
20,226105
```

When `Page` is found store 3rd column in `h` (page number).
Then if `href`, split the line by double quote and find the value and print it with page value.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. And in case of rename `page`? For example if `page` will be `7`, replace by string `Title`? Is it possible to get in in one command or must I work with this output? Thanks.

Comment: @genderbee added `Title`

Comment: Hi, working well, but when are 2 `<a href="">` on the same line, for example `<a href="123455">123455</a> | <a href="123456">123456</a>`, it get only first. Is there a way to get all links in html document? Get the string inside `""` only. Thanks.